# environment mapping using OpenGL and Cg

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, cg

I write a program to implement environment mapping using OpenGL and Cg shader language.But the result is not very right.When calculate the color of the model,we will blend the reflection with a decal texture.A uniform parameter called **reflectivity** allows the application to control how reflective the material is.

Firstly I list my fragment Cg code:

```
void main_f(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0,
    float3 R : TEXCOORD1,

    out float4 color : COLOR,

    uniform float reflectivity,
    uniform sampler2D decalMap,
    uniform samplerCUBE environmentMap)
{
//fetch reflected environment color
float3 reflectedColor = texCUBE(environmentMap,R);

//fetch the decal base coloe
float3 decalColor = tex2D(decalMap,texCoord);
color.xyz = lerp(reflectedColor,decalColor,reflectivity);//change !!!!!!!!
color.w = 1;
}
```

I set the uniform parameter reflectivity as 0.6.And the result is :
[image]

As we can see,**the color information from the decal texture is lost**.There is only color information from environment cube texture.And if I set reflectivity as 0,the model will be dark.
But if I change the color.xyz in the fragment cg code as :

```
color.xyz = decalColor;
```

I can get the right result(only has color from decal texture) :
[image]

And if I change the color.xyz in the fragment cg code as :

```
color.xyz = reflectedColor;
```

I can get the right result(only has color from environment cube texture) ,too:
[image]

And my question is :
Why it does not work when I blend the color information from decal texture with the color information from environment cube texture using Cg function **lerp**?

at last I list my cg vertex shader and cpp file:
vertex.cg:

```
void main_v(float4 position : POSITION,
                float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0,//decal texture
                float3 normal : NORMAL,

                out float4 oPosition : POSITION,
                out float2 oTexCoord : TEXCOORD0,//out decal texture
                out float3 R : TEXCOORD1,//reflective vector

                uniform float3 eyePositionW,//eye position in world space
                uniform float4x4 modelViewProj,
                uniform float4x4 modelToWorld
                )
{
        modelViewProj = glstate.matrix.mvp;
        oPosition = mul(modelViewProj,position);        
        oTexCoord = texCoord;

        float3 positionW = mul(modelToWorld,position).xyz;
        float3 N = mul((float3x3)modelToWorld,normal);
        N = normalize(N);

        float3 I = positionW - eyePositionW;//incident vector
        R = reflect(I,N);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"glew32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"GLAUX.LIB")
#pragma comment(lib,"cg.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"cgGL.lib")

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glaux.h>
#include <CG/cg.h>
#include <CG/cgGL.h>
#include "MonkeyHead.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int loop;
/* Use enum to assign unique symbolic OpenGL texture names. */
enum {
    TO_BOGUS = 0,
    TO_DECAL,
    TO_ENVIRONMENT,
};
const double myPi = 3.14159;
//for Cg shader
static CGcontext myCgContext;
static CGprofile myCgVertexProfile,myCgFragmentProfile;
static CGprogram myCgVertexProgram,myCgFragmentProgram;
static const char *myProgramName = "CgTest18CubeMapReflective",
                        *myVertexProgramFileName = "vertex.cg",
                        *myVertexProgramName = "main_v",
                        *myFragmentProgramFileName = "fragment.cg",
                        *myFragmentProgramName = "main_f";
static CGparameter myCgVertexParam_modelToWorld;

//bmp files for cube map
const char *bmpFile[6] = {"Data/1.bmp","Data/2.bmp","Data/3.bmp",
                                        "Data/4.bmp","Data/5.bmp","Data/6.bmp"};
const char *decalBmpFile = "Data/decal.bmp";
static float eyeAngle = 0.53;
static float eyeHeight = 0.0f;
static float headSpain = 0.0f;
static const GLfloat vertex[4*6][3] = {
    /* Positive X face. */
    { 1, -1, -1 },  { 1, 1, -1 },  { 1, 1, 1 },  { 1, -1, 1 },
    /* Negative X face. */
    { -1, -1, -1 },  { -1, 1, -1 },  { -1, 1, 1 },  { -1, -1, 1 },
    /* Positive Y face. */
    { -1, 1, -1 },  { 1, 1, -1 },  { 1, 1, 1 },  { -1, 1, 1 },
    /* Negative Y face. */
    { -1, -1, -1 },  { 1, -1, -1 },  { 1, -1, 1 },  { -1, -1, 1 },
    /* Positive Z face. */
    { -1, -1, 1 },  { 1, -1, 1 },  { 1, 1, 1 },  { -1, 1, 1 },
    /* Negative Z face. */
    { -1, -1, -1 },  { 1, -1, -1 },  { 1, 1, -1 },  { -1, 1, -1 },
};
static float reflectivity = 0.6;
GLuint decalTexture;
bool animating = false;//enable animating or not

static void drawMonkeyHead()
{
    static GLfloat *texCoords = NULL;
    const int numVertices = sizeof(MonkeyHead_vertices)
        / (3 * sizeof(MonkeyHead_vertices[0]));
    const float scaleFactor = 1.5;
    //generate texcoords
    texCoords = (GLfloat*)malloc(2 * numVertices * sizeof(GLfloat));
    if (!texCoords)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR : Monkey head texcoords memory malloc failed !" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    for (loop = 0;loop < numVertices;++loop)
    {
        texCoords[loop * 2] = scaleFactor * MonkeyHead_vertices[3 * loop];
        texCoords[loop * 2 + 1] = scaleFactor * MonkeyHead_vertices[3 * loop + 1];
    }

    //use vertex array
    //enable array
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    //assign array data
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,3 * sizeof(GLfloat),MonkeyHead_vertices);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,3 * sizeof(GLfloat),MonkeyHead_normals);
    glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,2 * sizeof(GLfloat),texCoords);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,3 * MonkeyHead_num_of_triangles,
        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,MonkeyHead_triangles);
}


//read bmp image file
AUX_RGBImageRec *LoadBMP(const char *FileName)
{
    FILE *File = NULL;
    if(!FileName)
        return NULL;
    File = fopen(FileName,"r");
    if (File)
    {
        fclose(File);
        return auxDIBImageLoad(FileName);
    }
    return NULL;
}

//load decal texture from a bmp file
int loadDecalTexture()
{
    int status = 1;
    AUX_RGBImageRec *TextureImage = NULL;
    if ((TextureImage = LoadBMP(decalBmpFile)))
    {
        glGenTextures(1,&decalTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,decalTexture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,TextureImage->sizeX,
            TextureImage->sizeY,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            TextureImage->data);//指定纹理
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);//指定过滤模式
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    }
    else
        status = 0;
    if (TextureImage)
    {
        if (TextureImage->data)
            free(TextureImage->data);
        free(TextureImage);
    }

    return status;
}

//load cube map from 6 bmp files
int loadCubeMap()
{
    int status = 1;
    AUX_RGBImageRec *TextureImage[6] = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
    for (loop = 0;loop < 6;++loop)
    {
        if (!(TextureImage[loop] = LoadBMP(bmpFile[loop])))
        {
            cout << "ERROR :load bmp file " << loop << " failed !" << endl;
            status = 0;
        }
    }

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, TextureImage[0] ->sizeX, TextureImage[0] ->sizeY,
        0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[0] ->data);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, TextureImage[1] ->sizeX, TextureImage[1] ->sizeY,
        0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[1] ->data);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, TextureImage[2] ->sizeX, TextureImage[2] ->sizeY,
        0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[2] ->data);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, TextureImage[3] ->sizeX, TextureImage[3] ->sizeY,
        0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[3] ->data);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, TextureImage[4] ->sizeX, TextureImage[4] ->sizeY,
        0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[4] ->data);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, TextureImage[5] ->sizeX, TextureImage[5] ->sizeY,
        0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[5] ->data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    //free memory
    for (loop = 0;loop < 6;++loop)
    {
        if (TextureImage[loop])
        {
            if (TextureImage[loop] ->data)
            {
                free(TextureImage[loop] ->data);
            }
            free(TextureImage[loop]);
        }
    }

    return status;
}

//draw th surroundings as a cube with each face of 
//the cube environment map applied.
void drawSurroundings(const GLfloat *eyePosition)
{
    const float surroundingsDistance = 8;

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(eyePosition[0],eyePosition[1],eyePosition[2],
        0,0,0,0,1,0);
    glScalef(surroundingsDistance,
        surroundingsDistance,
        surroundingsDistance);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,TO_ENVIRONMENT);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        for (loop = 0;loop < 4 * 6;++loop)
        {
            glTexCoord3fv(vertex[loop]);
            glVertex3fv(vertex[loop]);
        }
    glEnd();
}

static void checkForCgError(const char *situation)
{
    CGerror error;
    const char *string = cgGetLastErrorString(&error);

    if (error != CG_NO_ERROR) {
        cout << "ERROR : " << myProgramName << situation << string << endl;
        if (error == CG_COMPILER_ERROR) {
            cout << cgGetLastListing(myCgContext) << endl;
        }
        exit(1);
    }
}

//init Cg shaders
void initCg()
{
    myCgContext = cgCreateContext();

    myCgVertexProfile = cgGLGetLatestProfile(CG_GL_VERTEX);
    cgGLSetOptimalOptions(myCgVertexProfile);
    checkForCgError("selecting vertex profile");

    myCgVertexProgram = cgCreateProgramFromFile(
        myCgContext,
        CG_SOURCE,
        myVertexProgramFileName,
        myCgVertexProfile,
        myVertexProgramName,
        NULL);
    checkForCgError("Creating vertex Cg program from file");

    cgGLLoadProgram(myCgVertexProgram);
    checkForCgError("loading vertex program");

    myCgFragmentProfile = cgGLGetLatestProfile(CG_GL_FRAGMENT);
    cgGLSetOptimalOptions(myCgFragmentProfile);
    checkForCgError("selecting fragment profile");

    myCgFragmentProgram = cgCreateProgramFromFile(
        myCgContext,
        CG_SOURCE,
        myFragmentProgramFileName,
        myCgFragmentProfile,
        myFragmentProgramName,
        NULL);
    checkForCgError("Creating fragment Cg program from file");

    cgGLLoadProgram(myCgFragmentProgram);
    checkForCgError("loading fragment program");
}

//compute rotate transformation matrix
void makeRotateMatrix(float angle,
                      float ax,float ay,float az,
                      float m[16])
{
    float radians, sine, cosine, ab, bc, ca, tx, ty, tz;
    float axis[3];
    float mag;

    axis[0] = ax;
    axis[1] = ay;
    axis[2] = az;
    mag = sqrt(axis[0]*axis[0] + axis[1]*axis[1] + axis[2]*axis[2]);
    if (mag) {
        axis[0] /= mag;
        axis[1] /= mag;
        axis[2] /= mag;
    }

    radians = angle * myPi / 180.0;
    sine = sin(radians);
    cosine = cos(radians);
    ab = axis[0] * axis[1] * (1 - cosine);
    bc = axis[1] * axis[2] * (1 - cosine);
    ca = axis[2] * axis[0] * (1 - cosine);
    tx = axis[0] * axis[0];
    ty = axis[1] * axis[1];
    tz = axis[2] * axis[2];

    m[0]  = tx + cosine * (1 - tx);
    m[1]  = ab + axis[2] * sine;
    m[2]  = ca - axis[1] * sine;
    m[3]  = 0.0f;
    m[4]  = ab - axis[2] * sine;
    m[5]  = ty + cosine * (1 - ty);
    m[6]  = bc + axis[0] * sine;
    m[7]  = 0.0f;
    m[8]  = ca + axis[1] * sine;
    m[9]  = bc - axis[0] * sine;
    m[10] = tz + cosine * (1 - tz);
    m[11] = 0;
    m[12] = 0;
    m[13] = 0;
    m[14] = 0;
    m[15] = 1;
}

//compute translation transformation matrix
static void makeTranslateMatrix(float x, float y, float z, float m[16])
{
    m[0]  = 1;  m[1]  = 0;  m[2]  = 0;  m[3]  = x;
    m[4]  = 0;  m[5]  = 1;  m[6]  = 0;  m[7]  = y;
    m[8]  = 0;  m[9]  = 0;  m[10] = 1;  m[11] = z;
    m[12] = 0;  m[13] = 0;  m[14] = 0;  m[15] = 1;
}

//multiply a floar4x4 matrix by another float4x4 matrix
static void multMatrix(float dst[16],const float src1[16],const float src2[16])
{
    for (int i = 0;i < 4;++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < 4;++j)
        {
            dst[i * 4 + j] = src1[i * 4 + 0] * src2[0 * 4 + j] +
                                    src1[i * 4 + 1] * src2[1 * 4 + j] +
                                    src1[i * 4 + 2] * src2[2 * 4 + j] +
                                    src1[i * 4 + 3] * src2[3 * 4 + j];
        }
    }
}

void init()
{
    glewInit();
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    if (!loadDecalTexture())
    {
        cout << "ERROR : load decal texture from bmp file failed !" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,TO_ENVIRONMENT);
    if (!loadCubeMap())
    {
        cout << "ERROR : load cube map from bmp file failed !" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }


    initCg();
}

void display()
{
    const GLfloat eyePosition[4] = {6 * sin(eyeAngle),
                                                eyeHeight,
                                                6 * cos(eyeAngle),
                                                1};
    float tranlateMatrix[16],rotateMatrix[16],modelMatrix[16];
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    cgGLEnableProfile(myCgVertexProfile);
    checkForCgError("enabling vertex profile");

    cgGLEnableProfile(myCgFragmentProfile);
    checkForCgError("enabling fragment profile");

    cgGLBindProgram(myCgVertexProgram);
    checkForCgError("binding vertex program");

    cgGLBindProgram(myCgFragmentProgram);
    checkForCgError("binding fragment program");

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
    glRotatef(headSpain,0,1,0);

    //set some uniform parameters in Cg shader
    cgGLSetParameter3fv(
        cgGetNamedParameter(myCgVertexProgram,"eyePositionW"),
        eyePosition);
    checkForCgError("setting eyePositionW parameter");

    makeRotateMatrix(headSpain,0,1,0,rotateMatrix);
    makeTranslateMatrix(0.0,0.0,-5.0,tranlateMatrix);
    multMatrix(modelMatrix,tranlateMatrix,rotateMatrix);
    //set the Cg matrix parameter : modelToWorld 
    cgSetMatrixParameterfr(
        cgGetNamedParameter(myCgVertexProgram,"modelToWorld"),
        modelMatrix);
    checkForCgError("setting modelToWorld parameter");
    cgGLSetParameter1f(
        cgGetNamedParameter(myCgFragmentProgram,"reflectivity"),
        reflectivity);
    checkForCgError("setting reflectivity parameter");

    cgGLSetTextureParameter(
        cgGetNamedParameter(myCgFragmentProgram,"decalMap"),
        decalTexture);
    checkForCgError("setting decalTexture parameter");
    cgGLSetTextureParameter(
        cgGetNamedParameter(myCgFragmentProgram,"environmentMap"),
        TO_ENVIRONMENT);
    checkForCgError("setting environmentMap parameter");

    drawMonkeyHead();

    cgGLDisableProfile(myCgVertexProfile);
    checkForCgError("disabling vertex profile");

    cgGLDisableProfile(myCgFragmentProfile);
    checkForCgError("disabling fragment profile");


    drawSurroundings(eyePosition);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void idle()
{
    headSpain += 0.5;
    if (headSpain > 360)
    {
        headSpain -= 360;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void keyboard(unsigned char key,int x,int y)
{
    switch(key)
    {
    case ' ':
        animating = !animating;
        if (animating)
        {
            glutIdleFunc(idle);
        }
        else
            glutIdleFunc(NULL);
        break;
    case 'r':
        reflectivity += 0.1;
        if (reflectivity > 1.0)
        {
            reflectivity = 1.0;
        }
        cout << "reflectivity : " << reflectivity << endl;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'R':
        reflectivity -= 0.1;
        if (reflectivity < 0.0)
        {
            reflectivity = 0.0;
        }
        cout << "reflectivity : " << reflectivity << endl;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 27:
        cgDestroyProgram(myCgVertexProgram);
        cgDestroyContext(myCgContext);
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
}

void reshape(int w,int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)w,(GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0,1,1.0,20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
    glutCreateWindow("CubeMapReflection");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that the lerp statement needs to have it's values reversed.

```
color.xyz = lerp(reflectedColor,decalColor,reflectivity);//change !!!!!!!!
```

should be

```
color.xyz = lerp(decalColor, reflectedColor, reflectivity);
```

because the [lerp documentation](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/lerp.html) says:

lerp(a, b, w) returns a when w = 0 and b when w = 1 and you want full decal when reflectivity = 0 and full reflected when reflectivity = 1.

I see that the effect you're trying to achieve is akin to GL_MODULATE. You will need to multiple the values together, not lerp between them. Try this, it should work and give you the effect you want.

```
color.xyz = (reflectedColor.xyz * reflectivity) * decalColor;
```

Comment: So sorry,it does not work though what you said about the lerp function is right.In my program I have set the reflectivity as 0.6,Even I misuse the lerp function,the color information from decal texture shouldn't be lost~~~I am very curious~~~

Comment: Well, I'm not sure a simple multiplication is such a good idea, since this way a small reflectivity just dims the whole color, even the decal color. His approach of a weighted sum is not that bad an idea, I think.

Comment: True, I am not sure now to regulate reflectivity in that - but I'm certain multiplication is what GL_MODULATE does and should produce the right results.